# Why does a זב מחוסר כפרה have a פסח brought for him?

Tags: korban, maseches-pesachim, zav-zava

From what I understand, a three-day *zav* must offer *korbanos* related to his *ziva* and cannot, until that time, eat any *korbanos*. A *mishna* in chapter 8 of *P'sachim* says that such a person whose *ziva*-‎*korbanos* have not yet been offered [but, commentaries add, has passed those *korbanos* to the authorities to be brought] can have a *korban pesach* slaughtered for him, as it can be for anyone who can eat from it. Why is this? The *pesach* was brought after the afternoon *tamid* which was otherwise the last *korban* of the day; this *zav* won't, then, have his *ziva*-‎*korbanos* brought that day and won't be able to eat from the *pesach*, so why is it being slaughtered for him? Or, to put it another way, *Tif'eres Yisrael* says they **will** bring his *ziva*-‎*korbanos* for him the same day, but how can they?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tosafos in חגיגה  daf 2b (כופין את רבו) already discusses this, and brings it as an example of doing a minor infraction to allow a fellow Jew to keep a great Mitzvah.

> תדע דשרינן ריש תמיד נשחט (פסחים דף נט. ושם) להקריב לכהן אחר תמיד של בין הערבים כפרת חבירו כדי שיאכל קרבן פסח לערב אע''ג דאיכא עשה דהשלמה

If you look at the source - in פסחים daf 59a - the Gemara discusses this very question. Various answer are suggested.

One simple answer mentioned there is that birds are allowed to be sacrificed after the afternoon *tamid* - always. They are not considered to be "real sacrifices" - and this Mishna [only] refers to a Zav who is eligible to bring birds.

> אמר רבינא אמר רב חסדא הכא בחטאת העוף עסקינן שאין למזבח אלא דמה ‏

Others learn from a verse that after the afternoon *tamid* one can bring the Pessach and the Zav's sacrifices.

> ואין לך דבר שמתעכב אחר תמיד של בין הערבים אלא קטרת ונרות ופסח ומחוסר כפורים בערב הפסח שטובל שנית ואוכל את פסחו לערב‏